# Azure DevOps templates with children

Tags: azure-devops

I found templates in Azure DevOps it is great feature, but I can't find how to create templates of user story with childs (tasks). Is it really create user story from template with N childs (tasks)?

We have typical user story with 10 tasks. Now when we need new copy (for new device), I create user story and after create 10 task from templates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By reference to this doc: [Use templates to add and update work items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/work-item-template?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser), with work item templates, you can quickly create work items that have pre-populated values for your team's commonly used fields. However, the child items are not contained in work item template.

In the meanwhile, the [Create copy of work item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/copy-clone-work-items?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#copy-or-clone-a-work-item) feature allows you to create copy of this template user story including its child work items. Thus you could use this feature to create multiple similar user stories with N childs (tasks).
[image]

BTW, there is an extension: [1-Click Child-Links](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ruifig.vsts-work-item-one-click-child-links) to define Child links, or even to create child items, might be helpful, too.

**Update**>>When we use the [Create copy of work item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/copy-clone-work-items?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#copy-or-clone-a-work-item) feature, the new work item will show a comment "`Copied from ***`", this is by design, but we can manually delete it, as below.
[image]

Comment: Hi Константин, Does my answer work? Please check it and kindly let us know the result. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, It is work. Thank you. Do you know how to disable adding comment "Copied from Task xxxx"?

Comment: Thanks for your confirming. I have updated my answer, please check it. BTW, if it works, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235), it could help other community members who get the same issues, thank you.

Comment: I not accepted it, because now i try to use 1-Click Child-Links, but i don't understand how it work. Did you use it? Can you help what templates i need to create? I click on new button but nothing happened.

Comment: If you use 1-Click Child-Links, please refer to this blog: [Azure DevOps Tips & Tricks 2 : Create child tasks automatically](https://medium.com/@tharindrajayamaha/azure-devops-tips-tricks-2-create-child-tasks-automatically-7beb7756751b) for guidance. For example, you create a task template, click this button in user story will create a child task for it automatically.

Comment: Please make one more small update, Azure will add related links for every copied task, not only comments. It will be cool to disable it... Maybe it will be possibly in future.

Comment: Yeah, I totally agree that this is a wonderful suggestion, you could submit it here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion, the product group will review these tickets regularly, and consider take it as roadmap.

Comment: I tried 1-Click Child-Links  after reading blog post, for me it better solution then copy with deleting comments and related links.

Comment: I am glad that 1-Click Child-Links is helpful for your requirement better.